# Automate lines on a graph in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I'm trying to add lines to a graph based on another (variable) table.

The graph is of user activity by date and the (separate) table is just a list of important dates. Ideally I'd like a vertical line at each important date and have the graph update itself as time goes on. I'm not sure, however, how (or if) I could do this.

Comment: Are you asking if you can put vertical lines at specific dates to highlight those dates? Are you asking for specific dates that are static? You could possibly make a csv file with these dates and x,y coordinates if thats the case. To be honest your question is a bit confusing, do you mind rewording it a bit for clarification or adding more detail so I understand exactly what you are asking?

Comment: @imdannyboy909 I've sorted it now. I have a table of dates and the "line from data table" will create a line for every date in that table. This meant manually filtering this table down before I load it in but it suits my purpose for now, it would only be if I could automate this (perhaps creating a table based on manual filtering) that I'd need any more input.